# Convert VB6 to VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2008, vb6-migration

```
The code in VB6 is:
------------------------------
Load(Inter_pol_surfex)
------------------------------
The message error is:
------------------------------
Name 'Load' is not declared.
------------------------------
```

Can I recieve the code to fix this message ?

Comment: Can you explain a bit more?

Comment: Please be descriptive in your question. Very little information in here to effectively understand the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you're trying to display a form. In .NET there is no Load function to display forms, you have to create an instance of your form.

Replace

```
Load(Inter_pol_surfex)
```

by this:

```
Dim f As New Inter_pol_surfex
f.Show()
```

Comment: Work perfectly ! Thank you so much !

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
Private sub Load (Inter_pol_surfex as [type of variable] )

end sub
```

Comment: I'm not sure that declaring an empty sub will fix the problem... Load() is a function that is declared somewhere else...

Comment: When I put the code: Private Sub Load(ByVal Inter_pol_surfex As Single) End Sub The Error message is: Value of type 'Int_pol_surf.Inter_pol_surfex' cannot be converted to single.... I dont know with which type to put there..

Comment: Try object type but I personally do not like to use this type  
(you could use the gettype () when you have assigned the object)

you can not find the variable that is in the vb6 project ?

Comment: In the vb6 project is Load(Inter_pol_surfex)
I insert Private sub Load (Inter_pol_surfex as [type of variable] )

end sub
but I cant find type of veriable there... I try with almost everythink with types of veriable